# Assign value in vector based on presence in another vector in R?

Tags: r, match, assign

I have tried to look for a similar question and I´m sure other people encountered this problem but I still couldn´t find something that helped me. I have a dataset1 with 37.000 observations like this:

```
id     hours
130      12
165      56
250      13
11       15
17       42
```

and another dataset2 with 38. 000 observations like this:

```
id     hours
130      6
165      23
250      9
11       14
17       11
```

I want to do the following: if an id of dataset1 is in dataset2, the hours of dataset1 should override the hours of dataset2. For the id´s who are in dataset1 but not in dataset2, the value for dataset2$hours should be NA.

I tried the %in% operator, ifelse(), a loop, and some base R commands but I can´t figure it out. I always get the error that the vectors don´have the same length.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: And what about the IDs that are in dataset 2 but not in dataset1?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `hours` with NAs for `id` that don't match between `df1` and `df2`. Since both your data sets had the same values for `ids`, I added one row in `df1` with `id = 123` and `hours = 12`.

```r
df1$hours <- replace(df1$hours, is.na(match(df1$id,df2$id)), NA)

df1
   id hours
1 130    12
2 165    56
3 250    13
4  11    15
5  17    42
6 123    NA
```

data

```r
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(130L, 165L, 250L, 11L, 17L, 123L), hours = c(12L, 
56L, 13L, 15L, 42L, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
   id hours
1 130    12
2 165    56
3 250    13
4  11    15
5  17    42
6 123    12

df2 <- structure(list(id = c(130L, 165L, 250L, 11L, 17L), hours = c(6L, 
23L, 9L, 14L, 11L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 0):

First `match` ID's of replacement data with ID's of original data while using `na.omit()` for the case when replacement ID's are not contained in original data. Replace with replacement data whose ID's are in original ID's.

I expanded both data sets to fabricate cases with no matches.

```
dat1
#    id hours
# 1 130    12
# 2 165    56
# 3 250    13
# 4  11    15
# 5  17    42
# 6  12   232
# 7  35   456

dat2
#    id hours
# 1  11    14
# 2  17    11
# 3 165    23
# 4 999    99
# 5 130     6
# 6 250     9
```

### Replacement

```
dat1[na.omit(match(dat2$id, dat1$id)), ]$hours <- 
  dat2[dat2$id %in% dat1$id, ]$hours
dat1
#    id hours
# 1 130     6
# 2 165    23
# 3 250     9
# 4  11    14
# 5  17    11
# 6  12   232
# 7  35   456
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat1 <- structure(list(id = c(130L, 165L, 250L, 11L, 17L, 12L, 35L), 
    hours = c(12L, 56L, 13L, 15L, 42L, 232L, 456L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))

dat2 <- structure(list(id = c(11L, 17L, 165L, 999L, 130L, 250L), hours = c(14L, 
11L, 23L, 99L, 6L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```